# Android studio AVD manager is missing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

it is as simple as the question I have no experience with android studio and this is the first time I install it on my pc ever since I installed the program and I can't seem to find the AVD manager it's not in tools neither the icon is shown and not even when I press ctrl+shift+a and search for AVD keyword simply it says that nothing with this name appears is there anything I can do in order to show the AVD manager?

Comment: you can get help through this link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLEWa9vUfs8

Comment: Check this link - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be that the SDK Build Tools are not installed.
This should help: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/avd-manager-sdk-manager-missing-or-greyed-out-in-android-studio/

Comment: it is installed i have no problem with SDK build tools

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these options-

1. Press `ctrl + shift + a` and type `emulator`. Or you can find it from Topbar Under `View > Tool Windows > Emulator`
2. Press `ctrl + shift + a` and type `Device manager`. Or you can find it from Topbar Under `View > Tool Windows > Device manager`
3. Press `ctrl + shift + a` and type `Virtual Device manager.

Here is the screenshot of the View Tab.

[image]

Comment: all of this doesn't help you with the avd manager

Comment: @Kamal Then What do you get following these steps?

Comment: I can find all of the settings you just mentioned but the only one that I need is the AVD manager and I'm not able to show it.

Comment: @Kamal did you find out solution for this, i'm also stucked in same situation